# Calculate all unique permutations using nested loops in Python

Tags: python

What would be the python equivalent implementation for this C++ code:

```
char x[10];
for (int i=0; i < 10; i++) {
    for (int j=i; j < 10; j++) {
        calc_something(x[i], x[j])
    }
}
```

Thank you

Comment: Two while loops, each with a counter being used as an index in the list... but I would prefer using the native for X in List structure

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are some solutions that don't use imports, and assuming that `x` is already declared as a list containing 10 elements:

```
for i in range(10):  # xrange in Python 2
    for j in range(i, 10):
        calc_something(x[i], x[j])
```

Or using the `enumerate` function:

```
for i, el in enumerate(x):
    for j in x[i:]:
        calc_something(el, j)
```

Answer (score 6):

This is done simply with [`itertools.combinations()`](http://docs.python.org/3.3/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations):

```
import itertools

...

for i, j in itertools.combinations(x, 2):
    calc_something(i, j)
```

This gives what you want. Specifically, it will return the elements in this order:

```
[(0, 1), (0, 2), (0, 3), (0, 4), (0, 5), (0, 6), (0, 7), (0, 8), (0, 9), 
 (1, 2), (1, 3), (1, 4), (1, 5), (1, 6), (1, 7), (1, 8), (1, 9), 
 (2, 3), (2, 4), (2, 5), (2, 6), (2, 7), (2, 8), (2, 9), 
 (3, 4), (3, 5), (3, 6), (3, 7), (3, 8), (3, 9), 
 (4, 5), (4, 6), (4, 7), (4, 8), (4, 9), 
 (5, 6), (5, 7), (5, 8), (5, 9), 
 (6, 7), (6, 8), (6, 9), 
 (7, 8), (7, 9), 
 (8, 9)]
```

Answer (score 0):

simplest would be :

```
    for i in range(1,10):
        for j in range(1,10):
           calc_something( list[i],list[j])
```

instead of hard coding (1,10)
you can say
        for i in list:
            for j in list:

Comment: But this will run the calc for 8,1 and 1,8 which is what I am trying to avoid... 'calc_something' is symmetric

Comment: if you want unique combinations:
    `i_vals= []  
    for i in range(1,10):  
        i_vals.append(i)  
        for j in range(1,10):  
            if not j in i_vals:  
                calc_something( list[i],list[j])`